Android emulator shows pop up that says to force stop
Hi everyone I am currently running Ubuntu 24.04 and would like to run and code with an Android Emulator but I get the error that says to force close this even though the emulator itself runs as the picture shows. Can only one help me get rid of that error on Ubuntu?? Thanks in advance!
Here is the image
For this problem I tried to change how it was rendered but with little success.

Maybe helpful or related answers: ERROR Android emulator gets killed in Android Studio, The system ui isn't responding in android emulator (Flutter)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
